# Applying css class depending on subelements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to set css classes to items of a list depending of subelements matches a certain criterion or not. The structure is like in the following example:

```
<ul ng-controller="Navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Category A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="a1.html">a1</a></li>
            <li><a href="a2.html">a2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Category B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="b1.html">b1</a></li>
            <li><a href="b2.html">b2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

My model is the current page, say `a2.html`. If a link has the same `href` attribute as the model value, it should have a certain css class (`active`). This could be done with this expression:

```
<a href="a1.html" ng-class="{'active': currentPage == 'a1.html'}>
```

But this is a bit inelegant, because I have to repeat the file name (`a1.html`). Would it be possible to pass the current element to a function? Something like this: `ng-class="getClass(currentElement)"`

The next problem is, that I want to select parent elements depending on whether a child has the class `active` or not. If `<a href="a1.html">a1</a>` in my above example is selected, then `Category A` should get the class `active` too.

**Conclusion**

'stewie's solution works, but I came to the conclusion that Angular is not the best tool for this job. It is not a web 'application' (the domain of Angular) but static html which should be enriched a bit.

This simple jQuery snippet does the job:

```
var activeLink = $("a").filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("href") == currentPage();
});
activeLink.addClass("active");
activeLink.parents("li").children("a").addClass("active");
```

Comment: What happens when the currentPage() changes? Wouldnt you have to keep monitoring the currentPage() and then run this again ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done by using a custom directive on your UL element, which would traverse the list whenever the model is changed and set the appropriate 'active' class on matching items. See this [Plunker as an example](http://embed.plnkr.co/rh7LhYlrqmQhCtFR6HH9). Please note that the directive can be further optimized. It's only a demonstration.

HTML:

```
<ul menu ng-controller="Navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Category A</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="a1.html">a1</a></li>
      <li><a href="a2.html">a2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Category B</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="b1.html">b1</a></li>
      <li><a href="b2.html">b2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('Navigation', 
    function($scope) {}
  );

app.directive('menu',
  function(){
    return {
      link: function ($scope, $element) {
        var link, li;
        $scope.$watch('currentPage', function(page){
          activate(page);
        });

        function activate(page){
          angular.forEach($element.find('li'), function(elm){
            li = angular.element(elm);
            link = li.find('a');
            if(link.attr('href') === $scope.currentPage){
              li.addClass('active');
              li.parents('li').addClass('active');
              return;
            }
            li.removeClass('active');
          });
        }
      }
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But you have to use jQuery (and not only jqlite as part of Angular) to be able to use `parents`. Angular provides only `parent` what is not sufficient in this case.

Comment: Yes, but question did not make jQlite a requirement. For that matter, this could be done in plain javascript as well.

Comment: You're right, I didn't mention it and actually it is not a requirement at all. I mentioned the need of jQuery only for other readers.

Comment: Regarding your conclusion: you still need to use that jQuery logic inside the directive, if you want to keep everything [the Angular way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1095616)

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at @Stewei 's the solution for this. But writing up the solution using a directive for this just did not make sense to me. I think that the directives are only meant to be written when you are creating a component or perhaps when you are stamping out templates. Even for stamping out templates I would suggest people to use ng-include or something like unless you want the semantics that a custom element provides.

But, I believe the Angular way of doing this is to totally separate out the behavioral logic from the 'App specific' logic. I would argue that you write directives in such a way that they are independent of the controller around it.

Here is a plunkr that actually solves this, hopefully in the most "Angular way" possible. This can be further decoupled, if you could use some kind of a data model for all the link's and could possibly ng-repeat over that model. But that is a choice upto the developer. Since you mentioned that it is a static page, this solution probably suits it best.

http://plnkr.co/edit/DjaYi1ofpFKgKfhtakub?p=preview

In your original question, you did ask if you could pass a currentElement to the getClass method. I have asked this before and the answer is NO. The only place where you could pass a reference to the currentElement is in a directive controller, but that is currently out of topic.

Here is the code that achieves the task at hand.

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="NavController">
  <ul >
    <li ng-class="getCategoryClass('A')">
        <a href="#">Category A</a>
        <ul>
            <li ng-class="getClass('a1.html','A')"><a href="a1.html">a1</a></li>
            <li ng-class="getClass('a2.html','A')"><a href="a2.html">a2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="getCategoryClass('B')">
      <a href="#">Category B</a>
        <ul>
            <li ng-class="getClass('b1.html','B')"><a href="b1.html">b1</a></li>
            <li ng-class="getClass('b2.html','B')"><a href="b2.html">b2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="getClass('contact.html','contact')"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <input ng-model="currentPage" />
  <br>
  currentPage: {{currentPage}}
</div>
```

JS :

```
app.controller('NavController', 
    function($scope) {
      $scope.currentPage = "";
      $scope.currentCategory = "";
      $scope.pageActive = false;
      $scope.getClass = function(page,category){

        if( page === $scope.currentPage ) {
          $scope.pageActive = true;
          $scope.currentCategory = category;
          return "active";
        }
        else{
          return "";
        }
      };

      $scope.$watch('currentPage',function(val){
        $scope.pageActive = false;
      });

      $scope.onLinkClick = function($event){
        $event.preventDefault();  
      };

      $scope.getCategoryClass = function(category){
        return $scope.currentCategory === category && $scope.pageActive ? "active" : "";
      };
    }
  );
```